# How to put other ongoing streamreader thread on hold

Tags: java, swing, network-programming, thread-safety, swingworker

For an example if I try to build a file transfer mechanism on the server program to whack one file bytes from sender A to user B by capitalizing on their own existing connecting socket, so how could avoid it interleaving with all the ongoing chat stream coming in, i.e to keep clear wait and notify between this two threads apart from creating an extra serversocket at server side …

Many thanks
Kev

Comment: Connect via multiple `Socket`s.

Answer (score 3):

create a message protocol for your app which distinguishes between various message types.  then create a "file chunk" message and a "chat" message and whatever other messages you need.

pseudo code:

```
// sending method
public synchronized void send(Message msg) {
  // write message to socket ...
}

// receiving method
while(true) {
  Message msg = readMessage(); // read message from socket
  handleMessage(msg); // may want to push this work to another thread
}
```

Comment: r u indicating one socket for each client will suffice for this matter, if it is,then your answer didn't cut my question on concurrent issue for interleaving incoming stream

Comment: @Saint - yes, i am assuming one socket connection.  by implementing a messaging protocol, you can multi-plex various types of communication over the same socket connection.

Comment: one socket can only generate one inputstream, handle msg differently for their types won't sift stream flood in

Comment: I am not sure you geting my points, how could you build some "file chunk" message type to handle incoming stream bytes with possible a file or combined with some instant chat message byte

Comment: Like any protocol, you send a special command sequence before each type, or a head if you like

Comment: I am talking about one client socket is already tipped to receiving a file (of course it got such message beforehand). Then how it can get clear reading??????????

Comment: @Saint - in order to send a chat message, you create the relevant message and send it over the socket.  in order to send a file, you would send a "start file" message (probably with a length), then you would break the file into chunks and send each chunk (probably with some sort of session identifier).  each chunk is a separate call to `sendMessage()`.  this allows additional chat messages to be sent at the same time.  the receiver then dispatches the messages to the correct handler (either the chat display, or some pending FileOutputStream).

Comment: Ok, kinda laborous but feasible. Thnx

Comment: @Saint - such is life.  i believe at one point in time i saw a multi-plexor library for java which simulated multiple streams over one socket connection (i.e. it did all the hard stuff for you).  i'm sure there are options already around to do this type of thing.

Comment: @Saint - not following your question.

Comment: I was asking if I don't wrap inputstream in a reader(avoid char<->byte conversion) and read out String from raw bytes, how the application sift the string bytes or file bytes (the header are string too right?) :-(